# HP UX iostat on File System

Tags: filesystems, disk, hp-ux, sar, iostat

I have a server running HP UX 11 OS and i'm trying to have I/O statistics for File System (not disk).

Fo example , I have 50 disk attached to the server when I type iostat (here under output of iostat for 3 disks) :

```
disk9    508   31.4    1.0
disk10     53    1.5    1.0
disk11      0    0.0    1.0
```

And I have File Systems (df output) :

`/c101            (/dev/VGAPPLI/c101_lv): 66426400 blocks       1045252 i-nodes
/c102            (/dev/VGAPPLI/c102_lv): 360190864 blocks       5672045 i-nodes
/c103            (/dev/VGAPPLI/c103_lv): 150639024 blocks       2367835 i-nodes
/c104            (/dev/VGAPPLI/c104d_lv): 75852825 blocks       11944597 i-nodes`

Is it possible to have I/O statistic specifically for these File System ?

Thanks.

Comment: This is from the command line, not from your own program?

Comment: Yes this is from the command line

Comment: Ok then you should try our neighbours at ServerFault. This site is about programming new software, not using existing software.